# How to code a UWP MVVM ComboBox within an ItemTemplate?

Tags: mvvm, combobox, uwp

I'm trying to figure out how to display a category for a selected item in a ComboBox which is itself within a GridView.ItemsTemplate. Nothing that I have tried so far has worked. I've tried using SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath.
I can display the Item's Category in a textbox from within the GridView.ItemsTemplate, but not the collection in a ComboBox.

```
// FiledNotesPageViewModel ViewModel
public class FiledNotesPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
public ObservableCollection<MemoryItem> NoteItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MemoryItem>();
}

// Public Properties
        public int FiledNotesId
    {
        get
        {
            return _filedNotesId;
        }
        set
        {
            _filedNotesId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FiledNotesId");
        }
    }
            public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    public string Note
    {
        get
        {
            return _note;
        }
        set
        {
            _note = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Note");
        }
    }
    public string Category
    {
        get
        {
            return _category;
        }
        set
        {
            _category = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Category");
        }
    }

// MemoryItem Model

    public int FiledNotesId { get; set; }

    public string Note { get; set; } 

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }
```

FiledNotesPage View

```
 <GridView x:Name="FiledNotesGrid"
              RelativePanel.Below="FilterNoteGrid"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.NoteItems}">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" 
                               Margin="5"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:MemoryItem">                    
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                            BorderBrush="{ThemeResource AppBarBorderThemeBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="2,2,2,4" 
                            Margin="20"
                            Background="#FFF7F713" >
                    <TextBox x:Name="NoteNameTextBox" 
                             Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="NoteTextBox"
                             TextWrapping="Wrap"
                             AcceptsReturn="True"
                             Text="{x:Bind Note, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Margin="5,0">Category:</TextBlock>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="NoteCategoryComboBox"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding FiledNotesId, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  MinWidth="125">
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your combobox doesn't have an `ItemsSource`

You need to do something like this...

In your CS File create an ObservableCollection property to bind to.

```
public ObservableCollection<int> FieldNoteIds {get; set;}
```

In your view, bind to your collection

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding FieldNoteIds}">
```

Right now you're providing a template for how to display each item that is populated into the combobox but you're not giving it anything to populate.

MSDN Tutorial on ComboBoxes and Binding

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Best-ComboBox-Tutorial-5cc27f82#content

Comment: Adding ItemsSource="{Binding NoteItems}" to the ComboBox, produces the error below. Because the DataType is set in the GridView DataTemplate to the Model MemoryItem, the ComboBox cannot change the DataType back to the FiledNotedPageViewModel. Error: `Error: BindingExpression path error: 'NoteItems' property not found on 'MyApp.Models.MemoryItem'. BindingExpression: Path='NoteItems' DataItem='MyApp.Models.MemoryItem'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboBox' (Name='NoteCategoryComboBox'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'Object')`

Comment: Well look at the error. What is it telling you? It's saying that it can't find the collection NoteItems on your model MemoryItem. If I were a betting man I'd say each row in your grid is a MemoryItem. That's because your combobox is looking to it's inherited data context (the row it's in) for the property you're binding too.

Comment: In other words, each MemoryItem model needs to contain the combobox collection specific to it

Comment: Which is the part that I don't understand. The collection is an observablecollection, NoteItems, in the FiledNotesPageViewModel. If I move my collection to the Model, then none of the code in the ViewModel will have access to it, and it wouldn't be using the MVVM pattern. Am I missing something, or is there a workaround?

Comment: No you need two collections. One collection is the MemoryItem's for your grid. Then inside each memory item you'll need a FieldNoteId's collection